# How to change webpage background color with button using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, image, button, background-color

I'm trying to change a webpages background color using a button. I'm using a JPG for a button.

```
<head>
<script language="JavaScript">
 function changeBGC(color){
 document.bgColor = color;
 }
 </script>
 </head>
```

In the body

```
<img src="images/white01.jpg" alt= "White Background" width="255" height="38" type='button' value='White Background' onClick="javascript:changeBGC('#ffffff');return false" />

<img src="images/black01.jpg" alt= "Black Background" width="255" height="38" type="button" value='Black Background' onClick="javascript:changeBGC(#000000');return false" />
```

Comment: I'm on my phone so sorry for the mostly unhelpful comment, but this is like 1998 javascript. You should find a better guide... Mozilla's dev center is a good resource but I'm not sure if it's got tutorials for beginners...

Comment: Can you clarify what you want?

Answer (score 0):

On the `<head>` tag:

```
<script>
 function changeBGC(color){
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = color;
 }
</script>
```

Buttons:

```
<img src="images/white01.jpg" alt= "White Background" width="255" height="38" type='button' value='White Background' onclick="changeBGC('#ffffff');return false" />

<img src="images/black01.jpg" alt= "Black Background" width="255" height="38" type="button" value='Black Background' onclick="changeBGC('#000000');return false" />
```

Check it on http://jsfiddle.net/a7guj/

Comment: Html mistakes:onClick="javascript:changeBGC(#000000');return false",missing "'"